# How to not produce too many separate pages (files) in project?

Tags: php, optimization, architecture

Have take over project where they need to add a lot of different info to database and then edit it later. Like 20+ diffeent pages in style of `create_x.php` `edit_x.php` `list_all_x.php` sand that same layout goes 20 times considering that i use smarty templating language it separates php from html so total pages count is 120 pages (60 php and 60 smarty template files).

Where's page create_x.php and edit_x.php are basically same except button name "Edit" vs "Create" and that info is pre-populated, as well as code that adds to database is different.

Is there reason why i would want to keep it that way rather than merging edit and create page in same page and then logically pre-fill fields or change submit button value?

This will drop pages count to 60. Which is still a lot, is there way to make less pages still even though they all different, but have same usage add or edit info in database.

Like how this called some programming method where you use modules etc. i fogot i feel it can speed up a lot and make it easier if i design site engine first and then just feed fields i want to display to it and do certain actions based on fields posted etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `create_user.php`, `create_issue.php`, etc, just use `create.php` and do something like `create.php?class=user`.

The same goes for edit/list.

You'll need each class to have a list of editable fields, and their "friendly names", but you'll get rid of lots of templating stuff as well.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to whether there is a better way to do things is probably "Yes".  It sounds like the person working on the project before you took a cut and paste approach to programming.  Now, you are looking at refactoring the code.  I would simply to suggest to continue along you current approach.  Find areas where common code is being re-used over and over and make that code available via a class, common function, etc.  As you go through and do this, so will soon discover more code areas with similar problems.  Continue to refactor these.

Of course, if you think the current code base it too far gone and re-factoring it into something easy to maintain may be more trouble than just starting something from scratch and trying to match the output, then you can also take that approach and design something that makes sense right from the start.